# How to Circumvent Perl's string escaping the replacement string in s///?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm not sure what exactly to call this, but I've been able to reproduce my problem with two one-liners.

Starting from a file 'test.txt' containing the following:

```
foo
```

After running the following command (in bash):

```
perl -n -e "s/(\w)oo/$1ar/; print;" test.txt
```

the output is '`far`'

However, when I introduce a variable containing the replacement string,

```
perl -n -e '$bar = q($1ar); s/(\w)oo/$bar/; print;' test.txt
```

the output is '`$1ar`'.

What do I need to change so that the second program will also output '`far`' and what keywords do I need to learn that would have made this answer Googleable?

Also, I tried changing the second one to s///e, to no effect.

Edit: This wasn't really the question I wanted to ask, which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881345/how-to-circumvent-perls-string-escaping-the-replacement-string-in-s-when-its).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me (in bash; you may need to change your quotes):

```
perl -n -e '$bar = "\${1} . ar"; s/(\w)oo/$bar/ee; print;' test.txt
```

The `ee` evals the replacement part as a text string. See [perlop(1)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2fPATTERN%2fREPLACEMENT%2fmsixpogce).

Comment: `$bar="\$1.ar"` or `$bar=q($1.ar)` is sufficient. `$bar=q($1."ar")` to be warnings clean.

Comment: Haha, this does work for my toy script, but not for the full one (one critical aspect was stripped out)! I'll accept this one because it answers the question, and then ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping someone will come along with something better, but this works for me:

```
perl -n -e '$bar=q($1."ar"); s/(\w)oo/eval($bar)/e; print;' test.txt
```

I'm setting $bar to the expression that concatenates `$1` to 'ar' so that I can eval it in the replacement portion (using the `e` flag).

Comment: Oh, @maxelost's `ee` method is more graceful than mine.

Answer (score 1):

/ee by @maxelost is correct.

This works in a perl program
`$bar = q("${1}ar");`
`$str = "foo";`
`$str =~ s/(\w)oo/$bar/ee;`
`print $str;`

so I'm guessing this works in bash:

`perl  -e '$bar = q("${1}ar"); s/(\w)oo/$bar/ee; print;' test.txt`

in windows:

`perl  -e "$bar = q(\"${1}ar\"); s/(\w)oo/$bar/ee; print;" test.txt`